# matplotlib.colorbar should show monochromatic red spectrum

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, colormap

First, I normalize my data on [0,1], to assign the respective values to a color of the red spectrum.

```
reds = (data/data.max()).flatten()
rgb_data = np.array([(r,0,0)for r in reds]).reshape((x.max(),y.max(),3))
```

I  create a colormap

```
my_cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(rgb_data)
cax = ax.imshow(rgb_data)
```

The problem is that the colorbar

```
cbar = colorbar(cax)
```

spans also over colors with green and blue unequal to 0.

How can I customize it to span from black to deep red without going over green and blue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had it almost right

```
cax = ax.imshow(rgb_data, cmap = my_cmap)
```

You defined your own colormap but you also have to pass it as an argument.

Comment: If I enter that, I get the following Error: "File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/colors.py", line 392, in to_rgba_array
    raise ValueError("Color array must be two-dimensional")
ValueError: Color array must be two-dimensional" Is something wrong about how I defined my cmap?

Comment: Solved it: the array that is passed on to the ListedColormap must be the array without "reshape".